# How do I track states across runners in a DataFlow Job?

Tags: streaming, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm currently creating a Streaming Dataflow job that only carries out computation if and only if there is an increment in the "Ring" column of my data.

**My data flow code**

```
Job=      (p | "Read" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=topic)
         | "Parse Json" >> beam.Map(json.loads)
         | "ParDo Divisors" >> ParDo(UpdateDelayTable()))
```

**Data flowing in from pubsub:**

```
Ring [
{...,"Ring":1},
{...,"Ring":1},
{...,"Ring":1},
{...,"Ring":2}
...]
```

I want my dataflow to track the current ring number and only triggers a function if and only if the ring number has incremented. How should I go about doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Pub/Sub

There is no guarantee that `{"Ring": 2}` will definitely be received/sent by Pub/Sub after `{"Ring": 1}`.

It seems that you have to enable [receiving messages in order first](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering#receiving_messages_in_order) for Pub/Sub. And also make sure the Pub/Sub service receives `Ring` data incrementally.

## Dataflow

Then to achieve it with Dataflow, you can use [stateful processing](https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/).

But be mindful that the "state" of "Ring" is per key (and per window). To do what you want, all the elements need to have the same key and fall into the same window (global window in this case). It's going to be a very "hot" key.

An example code:

```
from apache_beam.transforms.userstate import ReadModifyWriteStateSpec
from apache_beam.coders import coders


class RingFn(beam.DoFn):
  RING_STATE = ReadModifyWriteStateSpec(
      name='Ring', coder=coders.VarIntCoder())

  def process(self, element, ring=beam.DoFn.StateParam(RING_STATE)):
    current_ring = ring.read() or 0
    if element['Ring'] > current_ring:
        print('Carry out your computation here!')
        ring.write(element['Ring'])


  # Usage
  pcoll | beam.ParDo(RingFn())

  # Check your keys if you are not sure what they are.
  pcoll | beam.Keys() | beam.Map(print)
```

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the comment. I have already set up message ordering on pubsub , so that would be less of an issue to worry about. The data is streamed at roughly 1 message per second, and ring changes would normally occur only on average every 3 hours, which means the function to write rings to big table will only occur then .

Currently there are only 10 machines streaming data into pub sub. Then reading from Pub sub , i can differentiate these 10 machines by the key "machine". Can i some how set this as the key?I'm new to dataflow and functional programming, your help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, when you publish to Pub/Sub, if you structure the machine name into the message, you can use that information later in Beam pipeline. For example: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/keys/. You can map your elements into tuples of (machine_name, ring_data). Also you can always use `pcoll | beam.Keys() | beam.Map(print)` to check if the key is what you intended. You can also use notebooks (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/interactive-pipeline-development) to prototype your pipeline until you are sure it's correct.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the help, it works now, I managed to assign the keys to my P collection using WithKeys(lambda x: x["key"]. Thanks again